# Conditional formatting based on text value input

Tags: ms-access

I'm doing a form and having difficulty in highlighting field based on textbox input. I cannot highlight the field that contains many information in it.

This is my input field,
[I search for "Family"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlwGC.png)

This is my field where I have multiple values in it, separated by comma

[I cannot highlight the entire field eventhough the word "family" is in that field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6pPv.png)

Anyone got idea how to solve this?
My form after using vba
[I searched for "words", this is the first record, it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK4qF.png)

[Next record, there is no "words" in the field, but it still follow the previous rule from picture above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Ofx.png)

Comment: The textbox is lower case, but the matrix is first letter capitalized.  One way is to ucase the textbox, and then for each matrix cell to ucase it before comparing.

Comment: Thank you @donPablo, but I wondering if the problem is regarding the multiple value of my result field (2nd picture)? I'm using keyword search by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On click of the Search button, the code checks if the textbox has the keywords.
2. It then loops through all textboxes to find textboxes with matching keywords and highlights them

---

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()


    Dim ctrl As Control
    If Nz(Me.txtSearch, "") <> "" Then

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" And ctrl.Name <> "txtSearch" Then

                If InStr(1, ctrl, Me.txtSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                   ctrl.BackColor = vbRed
                Else
                      ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

To reset textboxes on moving to next record

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    'Me.txtSearch = ""

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
                  ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
        End If
    Next
    cmdSearch_Click
End Sub
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, You've been very helpful @Santosh. But just one problem, something it will also highlight the field that does not contain any of my search word.

Comment: Didn't get you? Could you please rephrase it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question to insert the picture for clearer explanation. Do you mind to take a look at it?

Comment: Do you want that after click it should highlight only the first instance of textbox where the match is found and stop? Sorry, but still not clear.

Comment: My form is using keyword search, so when I enter any word, the form will return many record (pages) that contain the word. I'm intended the form to only highlight the field where the keyword can be found. Your code work just fine for the first record, but for the next record, it will also highlight according to the first record (the same column as the first record eventhough my keyword cannot be found in that said column). Thank you for your time

Comment: So when you move to next record just reset all textboxes.

Comment: It work great to reset the textboxes. Thank you!. Unfortunately, i needed some other column to be highlighted (in the next record) because it also contain my keyword search. I really appreciate your help, but still cannot resolve my issue. I'm trying to use conditional formatting as next plan

Comment: Write `cmdSearch_Click` at the end of `Form_Current` event just above End Sub.

Comment: I got an error that said ambiguous name detected: cmdSearch_Click. Never-mind @Santosh, I think maybe my requirement is too high to be done in Ms-Access. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @RidhwanZ. Join me here to fix it. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge

Comment: it said i need to have 20 reputation to message there, right now i only have 7

Comment: @RidhwanZ.  Oh ok.